# Disable Touchscreen Dell XT3 on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: scripts, systemd, services, touchscreen, 23.04

*Laptop Make and Model*

- Dell Latitude XT3
- Memory : 4 GB
- Processor : Intel® Core™ i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4
- Graphics : Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 3000 (SNB GT2)

*The Problem*

- Touchscreen becomes glitchy and clicks randomly and does not allow control of mouse cursor.
- As a result I am unable to login sometimes, because i am unable to type to password in the password box at login.
- After Log in, I usually disable my faulty touch screen on my laptop using the below command

  xinput set-prop "N-Trig Touchscreen" "Device Enabled" 0
  xinput set-prop "N-Trig MultiTouch" "Device Enabled" 0
  xinput set-prop "N-Trig Pen stylus" "Device Enabled" 0
  xinput set-prop "N-Trig Pen eraser" "Device Enabled" 0

I created a .sh script file to to execute all of these commands on startup The contents of the file are

```
#!/bin/bash

xinput set-prop "N-Trig Touchscreen" "Device Enabled" 0
xinput set-prop "N-Trig MultiTouch" "Device Enabled" 0
xinput set-prop "N-Trig Pen stylus" "Device Enabled" 0
xinput set-prop "N-Trig Pen eraser" "Device Enabled" 0
```

- When i add this script to startup applications, it is running only
  after login.
- I want the script to disable the touchscreen at the login screen itself. during boot process itself.

Thus i created a .service file with the below contents

```
[Unit]
Description=Disable touchscreen on startup
After=lightdm.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 6
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/disable-touchscreen.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When i run the script manually using /usr/local/bin/disable-touchscreen.sh it works.
But when i check the status of the .service file, it has an error saying
"Unable to connect to X server"

Some kindly help me to troubleshoot, why the script is unable to connect to X server when it is called by the service. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add to your question (please don't add in comments) the make/model of your laptop? This will help others search for and find issues related to their specific hardware problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `xinput` command configures your X server's view of the keyboard. Running it before you login, and start the X server (or Wayland), does not make sense.

You *could* login to your GUI, open a terminal and `echo "$DISPLAY"`. Try copying this definition (`export DISPLAY=...`) to
`/usr/local/bin/disable-touchscreen.sh`, or a wrapper script.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].